# Update Existing Documents in Cosmos db using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have created a data factory to Update my existing Cosmos DB using data stored in Blob as csv file.
The csv file contains two fields column "X" and "Y" and their values.
I want to insert new key in  my existing Cosmos Db as Y ,filter criteria is column X which is unique

I already created the pipeline ,and upsert the documents in cosmosdb.
But in current Pipeline old data is getting removed and only column Y is getting inserted.

Data in current Document in cosmos db

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad5adbfa882146ea8e7a0e"),
    "x" : "UUID",
   "old_key" : true
  }
```

Data in csv file

```
   x,new_key
   UUID, "new_value"
```

Expected output

```
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5dad5adbfa882146ea8e7a0e"),
      "x" : "UUID",
     "old_key" : true,
    "new_key":"new_value"

    }
```

My output which i tried(old keys are removed)

```
   {
     "_id" : ObjectId("5dad5adbfa882146ea8e7a0e"),
     "x" : "UUID"
     "new_key":"new_value"

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to implement incremental update or partial update for cosmos db.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dad5adbfa882146ea8e7a0e"),
    "x" : "UUID",
   "old_key" : true
}
```

change to:

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("5dad5adbfa882146ea8e7a0e"),
      "x" : "UUID",
     "old_key" : true,
    "new_key":"new_value"
}
```

As i know, partial update is not supported in the cosmos db so far.Please see this [user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/6693091-be-able-to-do-partial-updates-on-document) and this [feature statement](https://buildazure.com/top-10-cosmos-db-features-coming-soon-march-2019/)(i know this feature lack lasts so long already....). So, you have to contains all the properties in your new documents except `"_id"`.

I did a simple test:

1.load a csv file into cosmos db:

```
_id,x,A
5daeb1eda34d640184a71d47,123,ValueA
```

2.load a new csv file into cosmos db:

```
_id,x,B
5daeb1eda34d640184a71d47,123,ValueBBB
```

3.print two outputs:

[image]

Comment: In my case, it is just like adding a new key in each of the existing documents on the basis of common key(which is unique, key X).

Comment: @Tech_ninja Yes,append a new key is partial update,isn't it? As my answer said, partial update is not supported. If you want to append a new key, you have to pass a  total old document plus new key.

Comment: yes it is same , is there any way to do this using ADF?  so whole process is like - Reading key from csv > query cosmos db on the basis of matching  key( for fetching old document) > then append the new key and then upsert it in cosmos db. Thanks.

Comment: @Tech_ninja Did you find a solution for this using DataFactory? I have a similar use case.

Comment: Not able to find a good solution, but found an alternate one which is not an optimal solution. @RajatArora